# Git: replace commit history of Master with the history of feature branch

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase, git-history

I'm new to interactive rebasing in Git so I made a branch where I could squash commits ( `squash-branch` ) just in case I ruined something. I didn't change any of the files on the branch, just the history. I merged the branch to `master` expecting that it would take the commit new commit history of the `squash-branch`.

How do I replace the commit history of `master` with `squash-branch`'s history? To say it in a different mood, **I want `master` to have `squash-branch`'s history.**

I've already tried two methods of force overwriting `master` with `squash-history`. The "ours strategy" and `git branch -f master squash-branch`.

Please notify if you need more details!

Thanks!

Comment: ...what? Do they have shared history? Do you mean you want to *rebase* `squash-branch` onto `master`? Or something else? Do you mean you were just practicing on a copy of master, in which case now you've been successful why not re-run the same process on master? Do you share that history with anyone else?

Comment: I genuinely wanted to squash commits on `master` and made `squash-branch` to do so safely. I guess I was just hoping for a way to get my history change on `squash-branch` over to `master` without redoing the same thing again on `master`. But, I maybe this misses the whole point of a branch having a commit history. Do you think force pushing `squash-branch` to `origin master` could do that?

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` can do that:

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft squash-branch
```

Details in git-reset(1).

> #### `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]`
>
> This form resets the current branch head to `<commit>` …